# Qual a diferença entre halt, poweroff e reboot?

Tags: linux

Eu já ouvi varias vezes que caso eu queira desligar/reiniciar o computador pelo terminal basta executar uma destas opções :

- halt
- poweroff
- reboot

`poweroff` e `reboot` são bem intuitivos "desligar" e "reiniciar", eu só não compreendi direito o `halt` "parar"

Ao qual me foi afirmado :

> "O computador tem estágios de inicialização o `halt` manda para o estagio 0"

Fiquei sabendo também que ele possui 6 estágios.

Pela documentação do terminal não tive muito sucesso em saber quais são :

```
> man halt
...
DESCRIPTION
       halt, poweroff, reboot may be used to halt, power-off or reboot the machine.
...
```

#### Duvida

- O que de fato é o `halt`?
- Quais os estágios dele?

Comment: aqui vai mais um chute que outra coisa: Acredito que o HALT e para suspender/hibernar a maquina, ele nao chaga a desligar totalmente, mas tambem nao fica totalmente ligado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> O que de fato é o halt?

Halt é um comando que para todas as CPU's presentes no sistema.

> Quais os estágios dele?

Os estágios do boot são 6, como você disse, que são os seguintes:

1. BIOS - executa algumas checagens de integridade no sistema, procura pelo programa de boot, carrega o mesmo em memória e dá o controle pra ele
2. MBR (Master Boot Record) - Basicamente, carrega e executa o GRUB (carregador de sistemas operacionais [Grand Unified Bootloader)
3. GRUB - É a tela que mostra os sistemas que podem ser iniciados. Ele espera alguns segundos por uma seleção, se ela não acontecer, ele carrega o sistema padrão
4. Kernel - Monta o sistema de arquivos, executa o programa /sbin/init
5. Init - Olha no /etc/inittab para decidir o ***RunLevel*** do sistema, que são esses aqui:
   0 - Halt (é aonde o comando Halt te coloca)
   1 - Single User Mode
   2 - Full Multiuser mode
   3 - unused
   4 - X11
   5 - reboot
6. Programas a Runlevel - é aonde os serviços e programas são iniciados

Eu coloquei os estágios de inicialização e os estágios de RunLevel, para que não haja confusão. O estágio "0" que o halt te coloca, é no RunLevel

**Mais especificações sobre o comando Halt**

- Se você invocar halt sem parâmetros, ele simplesmente executa `shutdown`
- Se chamado com *--force*, durante runlevel 0 ou 6, executa `reboot`, caso contrário, executa `shutdown`
- Se chamado com *-p*, se comporta como `poweroff`
- Se chamado com *-w*, não faz `reboot`nem `poweroff`. Em vez disso, grava o registro de shutdown em */var/log/wtmp*.
- Se chamado com *--verbose*, mostra mensagens mais detalhadas no reboot, útil para debug de problemas com shutdown

**Referências**

https://linux.die.net/man/8/halt
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/Linux-boot-process/

Answer (score 0):

Existem seis estágios de alto nível para o processo de inicialização do Linux:

BIOS – Sistema básico de entrada / saída executa MBR
MBR – Registro mestre de inicialização executa GRUB
GRUB – Grand Unified Bootloader executa Kernel
Kernel – Kernel executa `/sbin/init`
Init – Init executa programas de nível de execução
Runlevel – Os programas em nível de execução são executados a partir de `/etc/rc.d/rc*.d/`

BIOS pesquisa o carregador de inicialização em um disquete, CD-ROM ou disco rígido. Você pode alterar a sequência de inicialização da configuração do BIOS durante a inicialização do BIOS.

MBR localizado no primeiro setor da unidade inicializável. Geralmente, `/dev/had`, ou `/dev/sda`.
MBR armazenou informações sobre qualquer carregador de boot; em nosso caso, é ter informações sobre o carregador de boot GRUB.

GRUB significa Grand Unified Bootloader.
Ele armazena todas as informações sobre a imagem do sistema operacional para carregar e executar.

Quando o kernel carrega, ele monta o sistema de arquivos raiz e executa `/sbin/init` programa.

Init
Ele verifica o arquivo `/etc/inittab` para decidir o nível de execução do Linux.

Existem sete (7) níveis de execução disponíveis com o sistema operacional Linux:

```
0 – parar
1 – modo de usuário único
2 – Multiusuário, sem NFS
3 – Modo multiusuário completo
4 – não utilizado
5 – X11
6 – reinício
```

Runlevel
Um nível de execução padrão identificado; ele executará todos os programas necessários para aquele nível de execução.

O sistema verificará e executará programas de nível de execução dos seguintes diretórios:

```
Run level 0 – /etc/rc.d/rc0.d/
Run level 1 – /etc/rc.d/rc1.d/
Run level 2 – /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/
Run level 3 – /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/
Run level 4 – /etc/rc.d/rc4.d/
Run level 5 – /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/
Run level 6 – /etc/rc.d/rc6.d/
```

Há um diretório com link simbólico também disponível em “/etc” directory, /etc/rc0.d é ligado à /etc/rc.d/rc0.d e assim por diante.

**Referência:**

[Linux Boot Process – Step-by-Step Explained](https://linuxconcept.com/linux-boot-process-step-by-step-explained/)